# RequestLog does not implement LifeCycle in jetty 9.4

Tags: jetty, logback, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

In Jetty 9.4 `org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog` no longer implements `org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle` and because of this my jetty doesn't configure `RequestLogImpl` which is responsible for writing access logs.

Any guideline how can this be solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.setRequestLog(RequestLog)` from here on out.

The old way was horribly broken and didn't catch 80% of the failed requests your context can have, no top level 400 errors, no context-less errors, and a surprising large number of other corner cases.

The RequestLog fundamentals was changed back in October 2014 to address all of these missing logging events. (This was introduced in Jetty 9.3.0)

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#setRequestLog(org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog)

Seeing as you are mentioning logback, I bet you are attempting to configure logback-access.

See the discussion at https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/269

Note that Jetty 9.4.15+ has a CustomRequestLog that accepts custom formatting.

Example usage (with slf4j)

```java
Slf4jRequestLogWriter slf4jRequestLogWriter = new Slf4jRequestLogWriter();
// the slf4j named logger to output to
slf4jRequestLogWriter.setLoggerName("my.requestlog");
// The format of the output. (See javadoc for CustomRequestLog for details)
String requestLogFormat = "%{client}a - %u %t \"%r\" %s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"";
CustomRequestLog requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(slf4jRequestLogWriter, requestLogFormat);
server.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```